# Digital Signage - After like 2 hours videos are slow

Tags: actionscript-3

I have developed a system, in AS3 for Android, where one video after another plays, but after letting them run for an hour or two, the videos show between cut or slow. That happens when I run it on an android with device, but that does not happen on my PC. I have used the "dispose()" of the NetStream and set the NETSTREAM to NULL. Could someone tell me what's wrong? I've also set hardware acceleration to "DIRECT" and RENDER MODE to "AUTO". Oh, I also use System.gc();

Comment: In order to improve the question you should share wholesome blocks of your code, not just random quotes from it. As a wild guess — monitor memory usage with **System.privateMemory** and **System.totalMemory**. Also check for event subscriptions you are not releasing, especially ENTER_FRAME.

Comment: Try using FLV container and `appendBytes`. If your testing videos are MP4 then the same data can be copy/pasted into an FLV (use a remuxing software). On the Flash side play the videos with NetStream in `appendBytes` mode, where you get a conveyor belt to the decoder and you just feed it bytes of FLV formatted videos, this will avoid memory issues since it never uses more than the current playing video. Recycle the bytearray to hold a different video (no **new** video objects etc).